# How can I implement strong parameters in rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

### My User model is as follows  (user.rb)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
 validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
 has_secure_password
 validates(:name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 50})
 VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
 validates(:email, presence: true,format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: true)
end
```

### My UsersController is as follows (users_controller.rb)

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  private
  def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name)
  end
end
```

So I should only be able to mass-update(mass-assign) the name attribute only.

But when I logon to rails console and type the following command

```
user=User.find(1)
user.update_attributes(name: "ck",email: "ck@gmail.com", password: "ckck9090", password_confirmation: "ckck9090")
user.save
```

I am still able to update email.

I didn't mention the :email attributes in the strong parameter .permit(). So how can I still mass-update the email attribute?

Am I missing something?

Comment: Is `user.save` failing?  If so what is in `user.errors`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to your answer is here:

```
 def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name)
 end
```

You are testing through the Rails console and not using the `params` hash. Rails has no clue where your arguments come from and will use them unless otherwise specified.

If you truly want to see your strong params in action, I suggest you do this:

1. Make a `create` method in your controller and verify you have the correct [routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) to trigger it
2. Create a user,

like this:

```
@user = User.new user_params
@user.save
```

3. Finally you have to add a breakpoint so you can see the magic. I suggest adding [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) to your `Gemfile`, that way you can stop the execution by adding `byebug` or `debugger` anywhere in your code. So all together, this would look something

like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new user_params
    byebug
    @user.save
  end

  private
  def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name)
  end
end
```

This is not very idiomatic but should work to illustrate. From there, you can type in `@user` in the REPL to see what was put in there. You *should* be able to see the filtering taking place.

Comment: Hey @Max Alcala, thanks for the reply. As per your reply, I updated the controller, routes file.  But when I try to access the url `http://localhost:3000/users/create?name=moniddd&email=mofffmoddmo@gmail.com&password=bhak99bddhak&password_confirmation=bhak99bddhak`, it throws an error `param is missing or the value is empty: user`

Comment: Are you able to stop execution via `byebug`? If so, then check and see what `params` evaluates to whenever you hit the breakpoint in the code above. You should see, at minimum, the `params` object. I also just noticed  you have `param` instead of `params` - there might be a typo?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know strong_parameters does not prohibit using mass-assignment altogether, but simply prohibits the use of `params` as an argument in mass-assignment. Therefore you can still do that manually.